# How do I calculate a percentile for a sum of 20 samples?

Tags: probability, statistics

How do I calculate the percentile for a total of 20 samples taken from a normal distribution?

Example:

What is the 90 percentile range for 20 work items with an average cost of £10k with a standard deviation of £4k?

Assuming a normal distribution is reasonable.

The 90th percentile for a single work item works out to be between £4.9k and £15.1k (which is quite a big range).

The average cost of all 20 work items would be £200k.

The 90th percentile for all 20 work items is between £X and £Y?

Comment: Are you assuming the 90th percentile from the mean, the left or the right of the normal distribution? I calculated the 90th percentile from the left using this z-score table (http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf) and got $10 + 1.28*4$, which is $15.12$k. How did you calculate your values and what method did you use to calculate them?

Comment: Oh I used an online calculator and filled in the numbers to calculate the 90th percentile for a single work item, I may have the values wrong though, I will check.

Comment: It seems like that you have chosen the wrong calculator — I checked that the values match when measured from the middle.

Comment: Still I need to know how to translate it to a sample size it's quite important but it might be difficult, is it? Cause I'm working on something that promotes new ways of working in IT....

Answer (score 0):

For independent and identically distributed $X_i \sim N(\mu_X=10,\sigma_X=4)$, then $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i$ has a normal distribution with mean $\mu_Y = 20*10 = 200$ and standard deviation $\sigma_Y=\sqrt{20*4^2} = 4\sqrt{20}$.

Then, using $P(-1.645 \leq Z \leq 1.645) = 0.90$ for $Z \sim N(0,1)$, you get

\begin{align}
0.90
&= P(-1.645 \leq Z \leq 1.645) \\
&= P\left(-1.645 \leq \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i - 200}{4\sqrt{20}} \leq 1.645\right) \\
&= P\left(-1.645 \times 4\sqrt{20} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i - 200 \leq 1.645 \times 4\sqrt{20}\right)\\
&= P\left(200 -1.645 \times 4\sqrt{20} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i \leq 200 + 1.645 \times 4\sqrt{20}\right)
\end{align}

Using similar calculations, for a single $X_i$,

\begin{align}
0.90 = P\left(10 -1.645 \times 4 \leq X_i \leq 10 + 1.645 \times 4\right)
\end{align}

Comment: What is this called in statistics / probability so I can check the theory? I think this rule is the one that handles the sample size: new standard deviation = square root of sample size times old standard deviation squared.

Comment: These follow from the properties of means and variances for linear combinations of independent random variables (see for example https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/166). The rule you state is wrong. If $X_i$ are independent and have same distribution then $\sum X_i$ will have mean = sample size x mean of $X_i$ and $\mathbf{variance}$  = sample size x $\mathbf{variance}$ of $X_i$. Then $\mathbf{std dev}$  = $\sqrt{n}$ x $\mathbf{std dev}$ of $X_i$.